# How do I clear jest state (spies, mocks) between each test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm having an issue where jest is not clearing state between tests. I tried calling `restoreAllMocks()` in a `beforeEach()` and in an `afterEach()` and this didn't clear my `jest.spyOn(x, 'y').mockImplementation()` stub. I also tried `clearAllMocks()` and `resetAllMocks()`, no luck.

My spec module:

```
function mockFeatureFlag(flagToMock: Flag) {
  jest.spyOn(FeatureFlags, 'singleton').mockImplementation(
    () =>
      ({
        getFeatureFlag: (flag: Flag) =>
          new Promise(resolve => {
            if (flag === flagToMock) {
              resolve(true);
            } else {
              resolve(false);
            }
          }),
      } as any),
  );
}

  describe('bufferMinutesForDistance', () => {
    it('for small distances uses min buffer of 3h', async () => {
      const minutes = await util.bufferMinutesForDistance(1);
      expect(minutes).toBe(3 * 60);
    });

    it('for small distances when HALF_GHOST_BUFFER flag is true uses min buffer of 3h', async () => {
      mockFeatureFlag(Flag.HALF_GHOST_BUFFER);
      const minutes = await util.bufferMinutesForDistance(1);
      expect(minutes).toBe(3 * 60);
    });

    it('for long distances uses 12h buffer', async () => {
      const minutes = await util.bufferMinutesForDistance(1000);
      expect(minutes).toBe(12 * 60);
    });

    it('for long distances when HALF_GHOST_BUFFER flag is true cuts 12h buffer by half', async () => {
      mockFeatureFlag(Flag.HALF_GHOST_BUFFER);
      const minutes = await util.bufferMinutesForDistance(1000);
      expect(minutes).toBe(6 * 60);
    });
  });
```

There are 4 tests here. In tests 1 and 3, where I am not explicitly mocking the feature flag to return true, I expect it to return false (feature flags are false by default). Here, I call `mockImplementation` to make the feature flag return true in test 2. However, when running the tests, I see that the flag returns true in test 3 as well. I was not expecting this, since it means the spy state is leaking between tests.

How do I prevent jest from leaking state between tests?

Answer (score 3):

This is an open issue (potential bug) in Jest: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7083

By default, Jest does not clear spy state between tests. They can be individually, explicitly removed in/after the test that creates them, or you can change your jest config to automatically clear spy state between tests. The following properties can be set in your `jest.config.js` to tell Jest to clear state between tests:

```
  restoreMocks: true,
  clearMocks: true,
  resetMocks: true,
```